# Unable to load local html file on API Level 30

Tags: android, android-webview, android-11

My app load local html file that located under `getFilesDir()` via `WebView#loadUrl()`.
Before `targetSdkVersion = 29`, below code is working.

```
        copyAssetsFile(this, "sample.html", getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        String url = "file://" + getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/sample.html";
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }

    private static void copyAssetsFile(Context context, String fileName, String directoryPath) {
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().getAssets().open(fileName);
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                    new File(directoryPath, fileName), false);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length = 0;
            while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
                fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            fileOutputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
```

Full example is [here](https://github.com/WataruSuzuki/WebViewExample-Load-Local-HTML-Android).

However, it's not working after change `targetSdkVersion = 30`.

- WebView respond `net::ERR_ACCESS_DINIED`
- Could load local html if it's located `android_asset`

How to load local html file on `targetSdkVersion = 30`?
Is it changed to be denied by Android FW??

Comment: We dont believe you as with that code a webview will not start talking about assets.

Answer (score 13):

`WebSettings#setAllowFileAccess()` is default to false when your app is targeting `R` and above for security reasons, note that you need to set the API level 30.   https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings#setAllowFileAccess(boolean)

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);`

Comment: Works great. Just one line of code. I found this issue in Cordova but I notice the latest version has a switch to enable this. See AndroidInsecureFileModeEnabled in https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/engine/SystemWebViewEngine.java

Answer (score 0):

to show local html files in `webView` in api level 30, I used this code

```
binding.webView.apply {
        visible()
        settings.apply {
            useWideViewPort = true
            loadWithOverviewMode = true
            builtInZoomControls = true
            displayZoomControls = false
            allowFileAccess = false
            allowFileAccessFromFileURLs = false
            allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = false
            allowContentAccess = true
        }
        val contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            this@DocViewerActivity,
            "${BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID}.provider",
            File(filePath!!)
        )
        webViewClient = MyWebClient(this@DocViewerActivity)

        contentUri?.let { loadUrl(contentUri.toString()) }
    }
```

now `WebClient` class is

```
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest
import android.webkit.WebResourceResponse
import android.webkit.WebView
import androidx.webkit.WebViewAssetLoader
import androidx.webkit.WebViewClientCompat
import java.io.File

class MyWebClient(context: Context) : WebViewClientCompat() {
private val assetLoader: WebViewAssetLoader = WebViewAssetLoader.Builder()
    .addPathHandler(
        "/public/", WebViewAssetLoader.InternalStoragePathHandler(
            context,
            File(context.filesDir, "public")
        )
    )
    .build()

override fun shouldInterceptRequest(
    view: WebView,
    request: WebResourceRequest
): WebResourceResponse? {
    return assetLoader.shouldInterceptRequest(request.url)
}

override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, request: WebResourceRequest): Boolean {
    return if (request.isForMainFrame) {
        view.context.startActivity(
            Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, request.url)
        )
        true
    } else false
}
}
```

and use `webKit` dependency

```
implementation 'androidx.webkit:webkit:1.4.0'
```